# Prevent boost xml Parser from crashing when wrong file selected in C++

Tags: c++, xml, qt, boost

I have a tool where a user can select a xml via a Qt Gui to set some parameters. The problem is. When the file is not a valid xml file my tool just crashes. I get the following error in Qt Creator:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_parser_error> >'
what():  /home/path/to/Executable: expected <
10:40:44: The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

Can I check if the XML is valid or can I catch the error and do something else instead of terminating?

I would like to show an error message and to cancel the parsing.

My code of the reading process is:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
...
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
ptree pt;
read_xml(filename, pt);
```

Comment: It's a C++ exception being thrown, and as such you can `catch` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/xml_parser/read__1_3_32_10_11_1_1_1_1.html) `read_xml` throws a `xml_parser_error` in case of an error, so just catch it.

Comment: So I can just use `catch (exception& xml_parser_error)`?

Comment: oh. thanks. Can catch the exception anywhere? I would like to catch it in my Qt MainWindow.

Comment: Sure, that's possible.

Comment: what am I missing now? I get the error in my IDE: `unknown type name 'xml_parser_error'`

Comment: The namespace? It is `boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_parser_error`.

Comment: oh. Thats a thing I should have known.. Thank you a lot.